# Why should I need to give the full mysqldump path when doing a database dump in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a mysql database dump in a php class.

I am executing the following code but only an empty dump file will create. But the same command works fine when I execute it in the command line.

```
$script = 'mysqldump -h ' . DB_HOST . ' -u ' . DB_USER . ' -p' . DB_PASSWORD . ' ' . DB_NAME . ' > ' . DB_DUMP_PATH . 'mysql-db-dump-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.sql';
exec($script);
```

But when I give the full path of mysqldump, the dump file create correctly.

```
$script = '/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h ' . DB_HOST . ' -u ' . DB_USER . ' -p' . DB_PASSWORD . ' ' . DB_NAME . ' > ' . DB_DUMP_PATH . 'mysql-db-dump-' . date('Y-m-d') . '.sql';
exec($script);
```

But I saw most of the tutorials, they just use mysqldump command. Not the full path. What is the reason behind this? I am planing to use this in both unix and windows environment.

Is it possible to get the mysqldump path in php for both environments?

Comment: on `linux` you can use `exec("which mysqldump");` to get `mysqldump` path, and on `windows`, do `$path = getenv('PATH'); ` and then `explode(';',$path);`, then loop over elements to find `mysqldump` path

Comment: This looks as if the `mysqldump` in your `$PATH` is not the same as `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump`; e.g. it could be `/usr/bin/mysqldump` - and apparently each of the executables works differently (different versions perhaps? See what `mysqldump --version` and `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump --version` gives you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid path by copying `mysqldump` and `mysql` commands from `/usr/local/mysql/bin/` to `/usr/bin/` path.